# Copy Eclipse / Android Project - now errors when running it

Tags: android, eclipse

I have encountered an odd problem after I copied my Exclipse project.

In my workspace I have "my_base_project". When done, I wanted to create a copy of the project for a specific customer, so I copied the folder into same workspace root with folder name being "my_spinoff_project".

I then search and replaced all text strings "com.example.base" to "com.example.spinoff" in .java and .xml files. I then imported in Eclipse and got this far error free.

However, when running I get this error:

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate application
>   com.example.spinoff.MicApp: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   com.example.spinoff.MicApp

From AndroidManifest.xml

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  package="com.example.spinoff"
  android:versionCode="1"
  android:versionName="0.1" 
>
  <uses-sdk
    android:minSdkVersion="8"                
    android:targetSdkVersion="17" 
  />        
  <uses-permission android:name="com.example.spinoff.permission.MAPS_RECEIVE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="com.google.android.providers.gsf.permission.READ_GSERVICES" />    
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />  
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />


  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location" android:required="false" />  
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.gps" android:required="false" />      
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.location.network" android:required="false" />



  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" android:required="true" />
  <application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/replace__logo__app_110_110"
    android:label="@string/MicAppName"
    android:theme="@style/MicTheme"
    android:name="com.example.spinoff.MicApp"    
  >



    <uses-library
      android:name="com.google.android.maps"
      android:required="false" 
    />





        <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Main" android:label="@string/MicMainName" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Prefs" android:label="@string/titlePreferences" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Browser" android:label="@string/titleBrowser">
       </activity>       








       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Contact" android:label="@string/titleContact" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.News" android:label="@string/titleNews" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Catalog" android:label="@string/titleCatalog" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.Visit" android:label="@string/titleLinks" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.MSGallery" android:label="@string/titleGallery"
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" 
       />

       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.MSMap" android:label="@string/titleMaps" />
       <activity android:name="com.example.spinoff.MSCalendar" android:label="@string/titleCalendar" />

<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
android:value="" />




  </application>
</manifest>
```

So... I don't understand that error. It can compile and run the project. Project just halts very early on when running with above error. Have I somehow missed replacing some text strings somewhere?

Comment: In manifest tag, check your package name.

Comment: Are you  used any third party libraries.

Comment: @Aravinth android-support-v4.jar google-play-services_lib.jar google-play-services.jar

Comment: @wtsang02 Added the entire manifest now

Comment: @Tom Go to Properties/ Java Build Path/ Libraries/ Add External JARs.

Check the Jar files in the Properties/ Java Build Path/ Order and Export

Comment: @Aravinth Are you sure? That have error on compile-time: "[2013-07-19 20:09:39 - Dex Loader] Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException;
[2013-07-19 20:09:39 - spinoff] Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: Multiple dex files define Lcom/google/android/gms/auth/GoogleAuthException;" Anyhow, I will post a screenshot how it looks like, but the original error message does not seem related to tthe .jars as far as I can tell? (But then again, I am relatively new Android/Ecipse and even Java for that matter.)

Comment: @Aravinth I am puzzled. After I then unchecked the .jars again, it compiled and ran on phone... I will return to see if problems truly gone...

Comment: @Tom previously i got the same problem i solved  using this method.If you want just accept my answer.

Comment: I will retest things later today. If everything clears, I will of course accept it. Upvoted answer + comments for now :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Properties/ Java Build Path/ Libraries/ Add External JARs. Check the Jar files in the Properties/ Java Build Path/ Order and Export.

Comment: Oddly enough this seemed to solve the problem. (Although I went back aftewards and unchecked them again.)

Answer (score 1):

Use Right Click on your Project in Package explorer>Android Tools> Rename Application Package to do this.

Ensure that your Spinoff copy builds correctly before you do the app package rename.

Comment: I need to copy the project first since I need one project for each customer. There is nothing to rename now. (I guess I could try it all over again byt copying existing project to new folder and then renames it. I will try if I don't make progress otherwise.)

Comment: Yea try all over. Make a copy of the existing working copy and ensure that this copy builds  and then rename the package using the tool. (This copying stuff would be easier if you are using SVN)

Comment: And I think package names with "example" will not be accepted in PlayStore.